# robocopy recursive - trying to copy particular files from source to destination

Tags: robocopy

I have a folder structure, let's call it C:\source, and beneath it are various folders. In those folders are a variety of files. I want robocopy to copy all .DOC files in the entire source tree to a destination, let's call it C:\destination

I am not particularly interested in the folders they came out of and would prefer that it just dump all of the .DOC files into the destination folder.

```
robocopy c:\source c:\destination *.doc
```

only seems to look in the c:\source directly without checking in any subfolders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690245/robocopy-copy-folders-content-to-a-single-folder

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy just complicates the task. A much simpler tool to use here is the
old [copy command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) combined with
[FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html):

```
for /r source-folder %f in (*.doc) do @copy "%f" target-folder
```

If you wish to compare this command with an example of using
`robocopy`, see the article
[Flattening a directory tree with RoboCopy](https://zeleskitech.com/2015/01/31/flattening-directory-tree-robocopy/).